# How to make Visual Studio 2012 uninstall the app when I stop debugging?

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2012 installs the app to the system to debug, which is fine in theory. But it's annoying to uninstall the app every time I stop the debugger. I want a simple and easy way to simply test the application like old VS. I hope there is a setting in VS that I have missed somehow.

Below is the link of the steps recorder file to understand the issue better. 
[steps](http://www.4shared.com/zip/oNIQXnk7/DebugIssue.html)

Comment: How exactly does Visual Studio 2012 install an application?  Visual Studio 2012 does not have the ability to manage a Setup project, Microsoft got rid of it, there were far to many problems.  You need to provide more information if you want help.

Comment: It installs the application to the new start menu, if you debug. After you close debugging, and even close visual studio, application still remains installed, just like default app.

Comment: Are you creating a Modern UI app? or is it a normal Windows application?, by the way, your link is dead, Microsoft didn't like it.

Comment: Modern UI app. And I know the link is dead. Microsoft didn't liked it at all, claimed copyright within hours. :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.removepackageasync.aspx